# Is the order of #include <...> items important in C?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

Is there a difference between the 2 sets of `#include` lines below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Is it important in terms of coding style?

Does it the order matter for any optimizations?

Is it a matter of coding conventions?

Comment: For `#include <...>` usually no, they're designed to be self-contained or include their own dependencies as necessary. For `#include "..."` you *never know* since some people write really awful header files that are order dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include` dumps the content of the included file into the current file.

If the included file is a properly written, well behaved header, then there is no difference, it doesn't matter, and not important for code style.

There are some exceptions.

---

[GNU `basename(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) says:

> There are two different versions of basename() - the POSIX version
> described above, and the GNU version, which one gets after
>
> ```
> #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
> #include <string.h>
> ```
>
> The GNU version never modifies its argument, and returns the empty
> string when path has a trailing slash, and in particular also when it
> is "/". There is no GNU version of dirname().
>
> With glibc, one gets the POSIX version of basename() when <libgen.h>
> is included, and the GNU version otherwise.

So imagine you include `libgen.h` - you get the POSIX version. But then you include `string.h` - would it override `libgen.h`? That very much depends on the implementation of both, and likely in some releases it does, or, if you include `string.h` first and then `libgen.h`, in some releases `libgen.h` wouldn't override `string.h`'s GNU version.

---

That `_GNU_SOURCE` is also an example on its own.

For example, you get [`mempcpy(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mempcpy) only if you do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <string.h>
```

Likewise you get [`accept4(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/accept4) only if you do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

Now let's say that for whatever reason you want `mempcpy(3)` but not `accept4(2)`.

You have to do:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

You can't include `string.h` before `socket.h` because then either you'll have to move `_GNU_SOURCE` up, and get `accept4(2)`, or not move it up, and not get `mempcpy(3)`.

---

Yet another example is inline code generators:

`generator.h`:

```
GENERATE(api_func_a)
GENERATE(api_func_b)
GENERATE(api_func_c)
GENERATE(api_func_d)
GENERATE(api_func_e)
GENERATE(api_func_f)
```

`server.h`:

```
#define GENERATE(api_func) int server_##api_func(const char* msg);
#include "generator.h"
#undef GENERATE
```

`client.h`:

```
#define GENERATE(api_func) int client_##api_func(const char *msg);
#include "generator.h"
#undef GENERATE
```

As you can see, `generator.h` is made to be included in specific situations that heavily depend on what was defined beforehand.

You should be able to do:

```
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"
```

in this order or in the reverse order... unless someone forgot the `#undef` part.

---

Yet another ordering problem occurs due to copy-paste bugs:

`api_a.h`:

```
#ifndef API_A_H
#define API_A_H

int api_a(int arg);

#undef API_A_H
```

Copy & paste to `api_b.h`:

```
#ifndef API_A_H
#define API_A_H

int api_b(const char* arg1, int arg2);

#undef API_A_H
```

`consumer.h`:

```
#include "api_a.h"
#include "api_b.h"

... api_a(1) ...
...
... api_b("b", 2) ...
```

Result: `api_b` undefined. And if I reverse the order:

```
#include "api_b.h"
#include "api_a.h"
```

I get `api_a` undefined.

Why is that? Because when copy-pasting `api_a.h` to `api_b.h`, I forgot to modify the inclusion guard `API_A_H` to `API_B_H`, so when the second file is included, it sees that `API_A_H`, and skips the definition of the API.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a difference? Yes. Is it important? No. `#include` basically copy-pastes the content of the header into your file. So the pre-processed form of your code does differ in your example, but as [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) noted, headers should, and basically always are written in a way such that include order doesn't matter.

> Are there importance in code styling?

You can use whichever order you like, often times formatters (like `clang-format`) will sort the includes.

> Are there any optimizations note about this order?

No